# Force a program to multicast on a specific network adapter

Tags: windows, networking, openvpn, multicast

An openVPN layer 2 client has 2 network adapters:

- Physical network adapter (192.168.1.0/24)
- OpenVPN network adapter (10.0.0.0/24)

Now the client wants to start (server) a LAN game.

Server advertises himself in physical network adapter with a multicast packet on 192.168.1.255.

What I want is the server advertises himself in OpenVPN network adapter. Is this possible?

Comment: 192.168.1.255 is not a muticast address, it is a broadcast address. Whether or not it is possible depends largely on the server and its configuration. Of course, the server also needs to be on the openvpn network.